# Epsilon Delta Proof of Rational Functions

Tags: limits

I'm stuck proving this problem below, how do I proceed?
[Solution](https://m.imgur.com/a/GtxL7uW)

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x):= x^{1/3}.$ We can assume that $x \ge 1$, since $x \to 8.$ Thus

$|x-8|=|f(x)^3-2^3|=|f(x)-2| \cdot (f(x)^2+f(x)+4) \ge |f(x)-2| \cdot (1+1+4) =6 |f(x)-2|.$

Hence

$$|f(x)-2| \le \frac{1}{6}|x-8|$$

for $x \ge 1.$

Comment: Do I only to show that min = {  ,   } and that is the answer?